# Does putting text directly in a <div> have accessibility implications?

Tags: html, accessibility

In general, I try to use semantic html to improve accessability. However, I'm working in an existing codebase and noticing that a lot of single-line text used in the layout is placed directly in `<div>` tags, to avoid the bottom margin that comes with `<p>` tags.

```html
<div>Team Average is 20%.</div>
```

Does this have direct accessibility implications, and if so, what are they? Will using `<p>` tags and adding a style rule to each one to get rid of the bottom margin produce distinct accessibility benefits? (I realize I could just set `p` elements to have no padding via CSS, but as this is an existing codebase, that isn't an option.)

I also realize I should use *more* semantic html where possible; this is just in situations where nothing more specific applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, assistive technology will function better, and the page will be more understandable when text is placed in paragraph tags, as opposed to divs.

Divs seem to be treated more like raw text. If the div uses line breaks to simulate paragraphs, then the visitor will be unable to easily skip paragraphs or move between paragraphs without listening to the contents of the entire div.

Using divs instead of paragraph tags is definitely sub-optimal. Whether or not it's a [failure of WCAG 1.3.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/info-and-relationships.html) is debatable. If it's relatively easy to change this out, it would be better to do so.

Comment: I would add that some visually impaired or dyslexic people customize styles on specific elements like paragraphs. For example the line spacing between paragraphs. When the text is not a paragraph their tools do not work properly.

Answer (score -1):

W3Cschools said "Any sort of content can be put inside the  tag!" (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.ASP) and in my experience there's no accessibility issues related to this.

DIV are for a division of space and it's no rules about their content however it's best for design to have html elements inside of if.

If you are concerned about accessibility rules i suggest you to check your website with some tools like the following ones:

- [aXe](https://www.deque.com/axe/)
- [Wave](https://wave.webaim.org)
- [Google Lighthouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk/related?hl=it)
- Valmolà

Comment: W3Schools is not a standards body, nor should it be treated as such.

Comment: Of course it's not. Anyhere the HTML specs says 'div is a container for *flow content*' and the flow content category includes plain text.

Answer (score -2):

If it's a single-line text, then it will not be a problem.
If the text has more than 1 paragraph, then you should use `<p>` tags.